# PowerPoint VBA Macro Mouse Over and Mouse Out

Tags: vba, triggers, powerpoint, mouseover, mouseout

I want to apply trigger animation when mouse over 
I found very helpful [tutorial](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17806/Mouse-Over-Animation-In-PowerPoint.html) so I can make the animation happen when mouse Over the button, but it allow the animation to happen only when the mouse come over the button again

What I need is to the required animation happen as below:
- when mouse over the button, the image appears
- when mouse out the button, the image disappears
(with no need to mouse re-over again the shape button)

Can someone help me achieve that.

here is the VBA code which in the tutorial,

```
Sub anim(oshp As Shape)
Dim osld As Slide
Set osld = oshp.Parent
'Note alter the name here to match the trigger shape
If osld.Shapes("Rectangle 7").ZOrderPosition = 1 Then
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
Else
osld.Shapes("Rectangle 7").ZOrder (msoSendToBack)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you try and implement the tutorial code? Are you getting errors? Can you modify the tutorial code to match your expected behavior?